# How to write Links with Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

As I am working on a backbone application, I came across the Router. My problem is, that i do not know, how to put links onto my website, so that backbone routes them. Imagine the following constellation:

Homepage: localhost/mypage

Now I want to set up a -Tag, that brings me to another page, like:

localhost/mypage/#!/subPage/subSubPage

Can someone help? How does the route and the tag look like?

Thanks!

EDIT 1:
Imagine situation:
I am at: `http://localhost/page/#!/de/home`
Click on  with href: `http://localhost/page/#!/de/masterplaner`
It brings me to: `http://localhost/page/#//de/home=undefined&page=#!/de/masterplaner`

Why?

EDIT 2:
The route I want to be called is:

```
!/:language/masterplaner
```

Comment: what does your current routing config look like? (http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes)

Comment: Do you want to know my routes? In addition: pushState and root are not set.

Comment: The urls are usally like this: http://localhost/page#de/home I link other views with <a href="#de/other">link</a>

Comment: Well I think the link is correct!? <a href="#!/de/masterplaner">Masterplaner</a>